# Send files over network - JAVA

Tags: java, android, networking

I am programming an application where the owner of the application has to be able to send files to other available devices in the network. At this moment I am able to retrieve all the ip addresses of the devices that are connected to the network.

Is it possible to send files to these devices if i have their intern ip address

Current code:

```
InetAddress localhost = null;
    try {
        localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // this code assumes IPv4 is used
    byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 254; i++)
    {
        ip[3] = (byte)i;
        InetAddress address = null;
        try {
            address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    try {
        if (address.isReachable(100))
        {
            System.out.println(address + " machine is turned on and can be pinged");
        }
        else if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName()))
        {
            System.out.println(address + " machine is known in a DNS lookup");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(address + " the host address and host name are equal, meaning the host name could not be resolved");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to have something standing by on the target device or devices - an app that will receive the file. Alternatively , you may be able to share the file using built in components and hardware like Bluetooth.

Comment: i can't accept your answer since it isn't a solution for my question, but I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Without help of server transfer over the internet is highly difficult. In some network it is not possible. only thing is you can transfer file to other device in LAN. Please look into [this](http://mrbool.com/file-transfer-between-2-computers-with-java/24516) it might helpful

Comment: Thank you. The only problem is that i can't install a client on the recieving devices. But thanks for your help!